# Inserting extra item 2A in HTML <ol>

Tags: html, html-lists

I'm sure this must have been asked before, but I cannot locate it.

I'd like to create an ordered list in which the items are numbered 1, 2, 2A, 3, 4, ….  I have no choice on the numbering as it must conform to a published standard which inserted 2A to correct an omission in an earlier version without renumbering.

Obviously I can use a `<dl>` and put all the numbers in by hand, and absent a better solution I'll do that; but it feels wrong.  I cannot do `<li value="2A">` as the attribute must be a number, and testing in Firefox 37 the "A" is ignored.  I've tried using `li::before { content: '2A' }` in CSS, but evidently Firefox doesn't use that to generate the marker as the [CSS 3 Lists](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-lists/) draft says.

Any suggestions?  I don't mind a solution that only works in relatively modern browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try not to rely on the *list-style-property* but on the CSS *counter-increment-property*. It could look like this:

```css
ol {list-style-type: none; counter-reset: section;}
li:before {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 2em;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 1em;
    counter-increment: section;
    content: counter(section) ". ";
}
li.special:before {
    counter-increment: none;
    content: counter(section) "A. ";
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Thing 1</li>
  <li>Thing 2</li>
  <li class="special">Thing 2 old</li>
  <li>Thing 3</li>
</ol>
```

You will have to apply the *.special*-classes manually though and maybe need some more for "B" or "C". But maybe this is worth a shot.

Comment: That does include the numbers correctly, and I don't mind having to add `class="special"` manually (as it's a rare event), but it no longer aligns properly.  The "Thing 2 old" text starts further in because "2A" is a longer label; likewise once the counter gets to 10.  A `width` CSS property on `li:before` and `li.special:before` seems not be respected.

Comment: You can style the :before-element by applying more CSS, so it will behave like a default list-point. See my edited answer.